# Is it possible to add message parameter for constraint violation template message?

Tags: hibernate-validator, javax

I have my custom `validator` and I want to add some error messages for it.
So I have next code:

```
@Override
public boolean isValid(final String label,
                       final ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
     constraintValidatorContext.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();

     if(label.length() > MAX_LENGTH) {
          constraintValidatorContext
                  .buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("{error.maxLength}")
                  .addConstraintViolation();
          return false;
     }
     ...
}
```

My message looks like `error.maxLength=You have exceeded max length of {0}`, so it has parameter of `maxLength`.

It it possible to add it when building constraint violation?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can.

You have to unwrap the `ConstraintValidatorContext` to an `HibernateConstraintValidatorContext` with:

```
HibernateConstraintValidatorContext hibernateConstraintValidatorContext = constraintValidatorContext.unwrap( HibernateConstraintValidatorContext.class );
```

Then, you can either use:

```
hibernateConstraintValidatorContext.addMessageParameter("name", value);
```

(and yours look like a message parameter (`{variable}`) so it's probably what you have to use - note you need HV 5.4.1.Final to have this method)

or

```
hibernateConstraintValidatorContext.addExpressionVariable("name", value);
```

if it's an expression variable (so using Expression Language and something like `${variable}`)